# Xamarin Forms Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Net.Http" that could not be resolved

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using VS 2017 and Xamarin Forms

I'm getting the following Warning when I'm building my app.

`Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Net.Http" that could not be resolved.`

I don't have any problems running the app on the Android Emulator (API 26)

I don't have the "System.Net.Http" as a package. I tried to install it to correct the warning but the warning wasn't resolved.

I did have problems deploying the app to my device because of this warning. This warning appeared as error when trying to deploy to my device (Lenovo API 23). Strange as it sound, I was finally able to deploy to the device (after hours of frustration) after restart the computer, VS, the device, cleaning the app and doing other stuff that don't suppose to make any sense!

So the question is how find the conflicts and how to "align" the version of the "System.Net.Http" between the libraries that are using the "System.Net.Http"?

Comment: Sorry for asking, but why bother with a warning as long as all is working..

Comment: As I said in my post, I had problems deploying the app to my device because of that warning. The output window was saying that the deploy was canceled because of that warning.Apparently after 2 hours of trying the error disappeared but I don't know why and this is what annoys me. I didn't change the code or did something meaningful to solve the problem. I would like to avoid problems like that and the waste of time in the future. That is the reason.

Comment: Have you found any way to resolve, as I am also getting the same error, but for the iOS part